# Definition of a norming set

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

In this [paper](http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/sm2003c.pdf), page $131$, in the proof of Proposition $4.1$, there is this sentence:

> We first note that if $V$ is a separable Banach space, the subset of Lip$(V)$ consisting of all weakly continuous functions is norming.

Question: What is the definition of norming?

From the book 'Topic in Banach Space Theory', Chapter $1$, page $17$, the author mention norming in the following sentence (Remark $1.4.2$ (b)):

> Let us observe as well that if $X$ is separable then not only is the sequence $(x^*_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $(ii)$ separating for $X$ but it is also **norming** in $X$. That is, the norm of any $x \in X$ is completely determined by this numerable set of functionals:
>
> $$\| x \| = \sup_{n}{|x^*_n(x)|}, x \in X$$

If the norming in the paper has the same meaning as in the book, then how do we interpret its meaning?

How to show the subset is norming?

Comment: First of all, it looks like there is a typo.  it should be a subset of $\text{Lip}_0(V)$, not $\text{Lip}(V)$.  In any case, what it means is this:  Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the subset in question.  Then for each $v\in V$, $\|v\|=\sup_{f\in\mathcal{S}}|f(v)|$.

Comment: So the author wants to show that for any $v \in V$, we have $\| v \ = \sup_{f \in S}{|f(v)|}|$? But how to show the equality? Do we show that both $\leq $ and $\geq$?

Comment: It works fine to me.....